# past continuous vs. past simple

Tags: difference, past-tense

> When I was first living in New York, I ate a lot of pizza.
>
> When I first lived in New York, I ate a lot of pizza.

Is it true that the first one is natural but the second one is not?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with either of these. Why do you think the last one isn't natural?

Comment: Gut feeling....

Comment: They are both "natural" but mean different things.

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think both are quite natural, but some people may feel there is a difference between the two, possibly how one expresses themselves through past tense or past continous.

Comment: When you are asked "What were you doing yesterday?" do you imagine being asked about ONE activity or more than ONE?

Comment: Hmm, it depends, in this case the time span of the question is 1 day, so unless you weren't doing anything that day, I'd probably think more than 1 @user1425

Comment: So, do you find these natural answers? I was doing the washing-up. I was reading a book. I was walking the dog. All these I was doing yesterday.

Comment: Yep. A few corrections-> *I was washing the dishes*, *I was doing all these yesterday*

Comment: OK. But yesterday is approximately 12 hours. Literally, it means that I was washing the dishes for 12 hours.

Comment: @user1425, yup but you arent going to list every single thing you did in that 12 hours now would you? :3 The point of that question is to find out what important/interesting things you did